# Cannot reinitialise Jquery DataTable on separate PHP script called by ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have a main page called `main_yladmin.php` where my ajax menu resides. Here's its menu code:

```
<!--Start Container-->
<div id="main" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="sidebar-left" class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">
            <ul class="nav main-menu" id="myTab">
                <li>
                    <a href="ajax/dashboard.html" class="active ajax-link">
                        <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                        <span class="hidden-xs">Dashboard</span>
                    </a>
                </li>                
                <li>
                    <a href="ajax/yl_dailysales.php" class="ajax-link">
                        <i class="fa fa-money"></i>
                        <span class="hidden-xs">YL Daily Sales</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="ajax/yl_inventory.php" class="ajax-link">
                        <i class="fa fa-barcode"></i>
                        <span class="hidden-xs">Inventory</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
                        <i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i>
                         <span class="hidden-xs">Reports</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Second level menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Second level menu</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--Start Content-->
        <div id="content" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
            <div class="preloader">
                <img src="img/devoops_getdata.gif" class="devoops-getdata" alt="preloader"/>
            </div>
            <div id="ajax-content"></div>
        </div>
        <!--End Content-->
    </div>
</div>
<!--End Container-->
```

I have a DataTable in both `yl_inventory.php` and `yl_dailysales.php`. Their only difference is the data populated on them from a query, everything are the same (table classes, id, etc.).

`<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-heading table-datatable" id="datatable-3">`

But `yl_dailysales.php` are not showing on the container and is generating this error:

> DataTables warning (table id = 'datatable-3'): Cannot reinitialise
>   DataTable.
>
> To retrieve the DataTables object for this table, pass no arguments or
>   see the docs for bRetrieve and bDestroy

Why is this happening when the DataTables are in separate scripts? And this is actually working on another main page `main_sysadmin.php` wherein I am also calling several scripts with the same table classes.

I have already tried `"bDestroy" : "true"`, `"bRetrieve":"true"` and `.fnDestroy();` but to no avail.

This is my jquery:

```
function TestTable3(){
    $('#datatable-3').dataTable( {
        "sScrollX": "auto",
        "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
        "sDom": "T<'box-content'<'col-sm-6'f><'col-sm-6 text-right'l><'clearfix'>>rt<'box-content'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6 text-right'p><'clearfix'>>",
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "",
            "sLengthMenu": '_MENU_'
        },
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "plugins/datatables/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [
                "copy",
                "print",
                {
                    "sExtends":    "collection",
                    "sButtonText": 'Save <span class="caret" />',
                    "aButtons":    [ "csv", "xls", "pdf" ]
                }
            ]
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: $('#example').DataTable(

Comment: @user4621032 uhm what?

Answer (score 0):

Clear the table before you reinitialise it

```
$("#datatable-3").oTable.api().clear().draw();
```

or

```
$('#datatable-3').dataTable().fnDestroy();
```